# How to detect file type from its content in zip archive?

Tags: java, gzip, apache-tika, php-ziparchive, zipinputstream

I have a zip archive that contains several gzip files. But gzip file's extentions are also `.zip` . I walk through zip archive with ZipInputStream. How can I detect inner file's type with reading its content rather than extentions. I also need not to change (or reset) ZipInputStream position.

So I need;

- Read files in zip with using inputStream (ZipInputStream in my case) Because zip in zip is possible.
- Find file type from its content.
- While finding file type from its content, inputStream position should not change. Because i will continue to read next files.

Example:

root/1.zip/2.zip/3.zip(actually 3 is gzip)/4.txt

Sample Java Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //root/1.zip/2.zip/3.zip(actually 3 is gzip)/4.txt
    String file = "root/1.zip";
    File rootZip = new File(file);
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(rootZip)) {
        lookupInZip(fis)
                .stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to get files");
    }
}

public static List<String> lookupInZip(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String entryName = entry.getName();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            //Option 1
            //String fileType = tika.detect(entryName);
            //Option 2
            String fileType = tika.detect(zipInputStream);
            if ("application/zip".equals(fileType)) {
                List<String> innerPaths = lookupInZip(zipInputStream);
                paths.addAll(innerPaths);
            } else {
                paths.add(entryName);
            }
        }
        entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
    return paths;
}
```

If I use option 1, '3.zip' is evaluated as zip file but it is gzip.
If I use option 2, '2.zip' is evaluated as zip correctly by using its content. But when lookupInZip() is called for '3.zip' recursively, zipInputStream.getNextEntry() returns null. Because in previous step, we use inputStream content to detect type and inputStrem position changed.

Note: tika.detect() uses BufferedInputStream in implementation to reset inputStream position but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: "But gzip file's extentions are also .zip" - not usually. They're normally .gz. Any way you can persuade wherever the archive comes from to use more appropriate extensions?

Comment: It is not possible, because I have zip files already. I use apache-tika to detect file type from its content using existing inputStream but it causes to change inputStream position.

Comment: Well yes, it's got to read the data. You could wrap it in a `BufferedInputStream` though, and reset it.

Comment: Use `Tika.detect(File)` or `Files.probeContentType`

Comment: I added java example that uses Tika as well.

Comment: Tika _should_ wrap detectors in BufferedInputStream and reset the stream after detection. The simplest way to get embedded file type detection is with tika-server /rmeta endpoint or tika-app -J commandline option.  These both use the RecursiveParserWrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The first two bytes are enough to see if it is likely a zip file, likely a gzip file, or certainly something else.

If the first two bytes are `0x50 0x4b`, then it is likely a zip file. If the first two bytes are `0x1f 0x8b`, then it is likely a gzip file. If it is neither, then the file is something else.

The first two bytes matching is not a guarantee it is that type, but it appears from your structure that it is usually one or the other, and you can use the extension as further corroborating evidence that it is compressed.

As for not changing the position, you need a way to peek at the first two bytes without advancing the position, or a way to get them and then unget them to return the position to where it was.